# Python typing issue for child classes

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

This question is to clarify my doubts related to python typing

```py
from typing import Union

class ParentClass:
    parent_prop = 1

class ChildA(ParentClass):
    child_a_prop = 2

class ChildB(ParentClass):
    child_b_prop = 3

def method_body(val) -> ParentClass:
    if val:
        return ChildA()
    else:
        return ChildB()

def another_method() -> ChildA:
    return method_body(True)

print(another_method().child_a_prop)
```

In the above piece of code, the linting tool I used is printing error as below

```
error: Incompatible return value type (got "ParentClass", expected "ChildA")
```

(where I do *method_body(True)*)

I have also set the `method_body` return type as  `Union[ChildA, ChildB]`.
This will result `error: Incompatible return value type (got "Union[ChildA, ChildB]", expected "ChildA")`

I am looking for a better way to do this.
If anyone knows the solution, your help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

mypy does not do runtime analysis so it cannot guess that calling
`method_body` with argument `True` will always result in a `ChildA` object.  So the error it produces does make sense.

You have to guide mypy in some way to tell him that you know what you are doing and that `another_method` indeed produces a `ChildA` object when called with argument `True`.  One is to use a [`cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast):

```py
from typing import cast
def another_method() -> ChildA:
    return cast(ChildA, method_body(True))
```

Another one is to add an assertion:

```py
def another_method() -> ChildA:
    result = method_body(True)
    assert isinstance(result, ChildA)
    return result
```

The difference between the two is that the `cast` does not have any runtime implication.  You can think of it as a comment put here to guide mypy in its checks, but the `cast` function only returns its second parameter, ie, here is the body of `cast`:

```py
def cast(typ, val):
    return val
```

Whereas the `assert` can naturally raise an `AssertionError` error (not in that case obviously, but in general).

Answer (score 3):

Naturally `ParentClass` isn't compatible with `ChildA` since not all `ParentClass` instances will be `ChildA`. The same goes for `Union[ChildA, ChildB]`.

In order for `another_method` to pass type checking, we need to provide the type checker with additional information about the runtime types involved, namely that `method_boy(True)` will always return a `ChildA`, not just a `ParentClass`. This can be accomplished using [`typing.cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast):

```
def another_method() -> ChildA:
    return typing.cast(ChildA, method_body(True))
```